# Why isn't there any terminal program using USB?

Tags: networking, usb, rs232, hyperterminal

I often use HyperTerminal in Windows XP. The problem is that it just supports COM and telnet. I know COM Port is very old-fashioned, but I can't replace it with USB because there is no such program for USB.
Is USB bad for connecting computers? Or I just mistaked something?

Comment: Which part of this text is your actual question? What are you asking about and what exactly are you trying to achieve. Please be more specific.

Comment: It's how USB works a computer is a host and two host computers cannot be connected

Comment: are you looking for sth like this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_USB

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use PuTTY instead of Hyperterminal as it's better in pretty much every way.

A terminal will commonly work with the following methods of communication:

- Telnet using TCP/IP
- SSH using TCP/IP
- Serial port using RS-232

The first two require the device you are trying to reach has an IP and supports the protocol in question.
The second requires the device be connected to your system via a COM port on Windows.

Now if you are expecting to do a RS-232 style terminal connection over USB, it must be a USB serial port.  You can buy RS-232 to USB converters.  Some devices have a USB port that implements a RS-232 to USB converter internally.  **On Windows, for any kind of hardware like this, you'll likely need to install a manufacturer-provided driver - this is probably why you are having trouble.**  Then, in `devmgmt.msc`, under Ports, you'll see an extra COM port.  You can use this to talk to your device through PuTTY (or Hyperterminal, if you insist.)

Comment: I am going to upvote this for the simple fact, you answer the author's actual question, because the question that was actually ask doesn't really have an answer.